# plot double precision error in pyhton by an accurate math library

Tags: python, plot, precision

I would like to plot the accuracy of float32 representations by using a reference value which does have a higher precision then a float32. I am aware of the option to use the ULP value to do the plot, but I would like to do it explicit with a reference value. (I need the approach later to test different arithmetic number representations)

I configured the reference and a test vector as:

```
mp.dps = 256
mp.prec = 256
mp.pretty = True

test_vec = np.float32(np.linspace(min, max, res))
ref_vec = mp.linspace(min, max, res)
sol_vec = ref_vec-test_vec
sol_vec = [mp.fabs(val) for val in sol_vec]

plt.figure()
plt.title(f"Floating point size {float_type}bits, accuracy")
plt.xlabel("Test value range")
plt.ylabel("Error")
plt.plot(mp.linspace(min, max, sol_vec.__len__()), sol_vec)
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

- Is there probably a better way to do such calculations?
- Any suggestions? Any other or better libraries to consider?

Comment: what library is `mp`?

Comment: I am using mpmath, sorry forgot to specify^^